# How to insert a QImage into an NxN grid layout in PyQt4?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

I have a 4x4 grid in a grid layout in PyQt4:

```
self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        pos = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2),(0, 3),
               (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3),
               (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3),
               (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]

        for position in pos:
            button = QtGui.QPushButton('button 1')
            self.grid.addWidget(button, position[0], position[1])

        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.move(300, 150)
        self.show()
```

What I need is to replace the `QPushButton`s with grids that contain images, so that it forms a 4X4 grid of images. Towards that, I know that I will have to use `QImage` but am not exactly sure how! Could anyone please help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a [QLabel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html) and add the images using [setPixmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop). The [pixmaps](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html) themselves can be created directly from a file-path.

Here's a simple example (specifiy the image file-path as an argument to the script):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, path):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(path)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        for row in range(4):
            for column in range(4):
                label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
                label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                layout.addWidget(label, row, column)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) else '')
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro. That was what I was looking for. Generally though, which one of the two is the 'preferred' way - QImage or QPixmap? How do the two compete against each other?

Comment: A QPixmap is optimized for displaying images on screen. A QImage is more low-level, and designed for accessing pixels directly. Widgets that display images (such as QLabel) will usually have a method for setting a QPixmap, but not for a QImage; so a QImage would require conversion to a pixmap first. Probably QPixmap is the most commonly used image class for general GUI design; the other three image classes (QImage, QBitmap and QPicture) are more specialized.